# EEVEE is showing screen space reflections in the viewport, but not in the final render

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I put an object (a puddle) in my scene and I used a Principled BDRF with Metallic set to 1.0 to have screen space reflections. I enabled them in the render configuration and I can actually see them in the (rendered) viewport.  However, when I render the project (F12) I cannot see the reflections (only the environment map reflection, not objects reflections).
Should I enable them somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I set the rendering samples to 1 and this (I assume) makes it impossible for the raytracing to bounce to the reflective surface and render the reflection. I am wondering why this works, instead, in the viewport (with samples to 1).

Answer (score 0):

sorry if this dose not usefull for you because i used google translate.

so first you have to do...(like imagine)
**before**
[image]

**after**
[image]
**second**
[image]

and i hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @luxury, unfortunately, while I am able to achieve the effects you say in a brand new scene, I am not able to have the reflections in my scene: only in the viewport, not in the final render.